# How to convert an iterative method into a recursive method (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, karel

I am working through a Java course on my own, but I don't have answers to any of the problems. This problem from unit one, based on Karel++, stumped me. There is a robot object on a pile of "beepers" and it needs to determine how many are in the pile and return that value. I need to convert the following iterative method into a recursive method.

```
public int numOfBeepersInPile()
{
    int count = 0;
    while(nextToABeeper())
    {
        pickBeeper();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public int numOfBeepersInPile()
 {
     if (nextToBeeper())
     {
        pickBeeper();
        return 1 + numOfBeepersInPile();
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Consider a function that will take a count as an argument, then, if its next to a beeper, increase the count and call itself with the new count.  If it's not next to a beeper, it's done.  In either case it should return the current count.  I might have made this too easy - not sure!